# Jquery trying to find specific parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list that looks like this:

```
<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------

<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------
<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to do now is to add a hover effect to the **card-stacked** once the user hovers over **card-link** but the only problem is that I dont know how to target the specific div. I dont want to add a hover effect to all divs just the parent of the a tag

Eg:

```
$('.card-link').hover(function() {
  $(this).$('.card-stackedl').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).$('.card-stacked').removeClass('hover');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jQuery methods **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** or **[`parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** :

```
$(this).closest('.card-stacked').addClass('hover');
//OR
$(this).parents('.card-stacked').addClass('hover');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.card-link').hover(function() {
  $(this).closest('.card-stacked').addClass('hover');
}, function() {
  $(this).closest('.card-stacked').removeClass('hover');
});
```

```css
.hover{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href="">card-link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------

<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href="">card-link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------
<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href="">card-link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------
```

Comment: closest fixed it! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this documentation should give you a hand here https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.card-link').hover(function() {
                $(this).parents('.card-stacked').addClass('hover');
            }, function() {
                $(this).$('.card-stacked').removeClass('hover');
            });
```

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.closest()` method to get the specific parent in the tree. You can also make use of `.toggleClass()` like:

```js
$('.card-link').hover(function(e) {
  $(this).closest('.card-stacked').toggleClass('hover', e.type === 'mouseenter');
});
```

```css
.hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href="">card-link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------

<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href="">card-link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------
<div class="col12">
  <div class="card-stacked">
    <div class="card-content">
      <a class="card-link" href="">card-link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
--------------
```